# Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to find a way around the errors

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Products
FROM Products
WHERE Code = @sku

Update #products 
SET Code = Code+'Group',
    ProducttypeID = @SimpleProducttype,
    ParentProductID = @SimpleProductID,
    ID = NEWID()

ALTER TABLE #Products Drop column ts

INSERT Products
SELECT *, null ts FROM #Products
```

Then I get:

> Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

I don't want to have to explicitly put every column in the statement , because the table might change and I just want to duplicate the row & change a few things.

I've tried a few workarounds, read lots of posts but no joy. Help!

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is a special type in SQL Server (and it has ***nothing*** to do with a date and time!) - it's a **system-internal** counter which is updated on each modification of a given row, in order to be able to detect changes to rows. It is **INTERNAL** - you cannot set it, you can *only* read it. And it's really now called a `ROWVERSION` column in newer SQL Server versions

Comment: The problem is that when you insert `INSERT Products SELECT *, null ts FROM #Products` you are assuming that `ts` is the last column in the table `products`, if it is then it will work fine, if not then you have dropped a column from the middle of `#Products` and are adding it back as null at the end. The solution, as Gvee has pointed out is to explicitly list your columns. Further reading - [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: using SELECT * / omit the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: THe error is: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

How do I  ( option 2 )  - insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column

Comment: @MartinThompson the only way you can insert the "default" value is by explicitly listing the fields in the `INSERT` portion. `DEFAULT` cannot be used without this.

Answer (score 4):

Always, *always*, **always** list out your columns in an `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO your_table (foo, bar)
  SELECT list_columns
       , here_too
  FROM   select_star_is_evil As seriously
;
```

The only excuse to not do this is laziness.

Being explicit with your code is vastly important!

`</rant>`

The error message is quite clear: you're trying to insert a value in to your *timestamp* column. Your final statement is trying to insert a `NULL` value.

The only way to avoid this behaviour is to not list the *timestamp* column in your `INSERT` list.

Comment: I disagree.  I want an exact duplicate of a row with everything and make a couple of changes - it's pedantic and wasteful of time to explicitly put every column and have to add a new column to this SP every time it changes.

Comment: Realistically how often does your table change? It should only take about a minute to alter the procedure each time the table does change. If you add up the amount of time you have spent trying to avoid typing the column list you have probably spent more time trying to avoid it than you would have spent altering the procedure 50 times, which is a year even if your table changes as regularly as once a week.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  It means if it does change , I don't have to think about it's impact elsewhere.

Comment: rather than being pedantic about being right , how about being a bit more objective. :-)

Comment: It is not being pedantic about being right, it is being pedantic about how to solve the problem. You have three options. **1.** Explicitly list the columns to be inserted. **2.** Change your timestamp column to a `DATETIME` column with a default. **3** Generate dynamic SQL ror your insert using `sys.columns`. So rather than dismissing the advice you are being given how about being a bit more receptive :-)

Comment: It's ridiculous if you want to duplicate a row. I can understand it in other circumstances , but having to track where this is and when schema changes is a waste of time.

Comment: The only reason I want to keep that column is because of the linq concurrency tracking.

Answer (score 1):

here you are trying to insert `null` value to column `ts`

another thing, here `insert` `table` and `select` `table` has different column list so you must list the column in `select statement`.

try.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Products
FROM Products
WHERE Code = @sku

Update #products 
SET Code = Code+'Group',
    ProducttypeID = @SimpleProducttype,
    ParentProductID = @SimpleProductID,
    ID = NEWID()

ALTER TABLE #Products Drop column ts

INSERT INTO Products(col1,col2)
SELECT col1,col2  FROM #Products
```

Comment: There must be a way around this ( other than removing the timestamp column )

Comment: You can USE: `INSERT INTO Products(col1,col2,ts)
SELECT col1,col2,null  FROM #Products`
and ts must be a null able column

Answer (score 1):

Here is your workaround.

```
/************************************************************************************************
CREATE SAMPLE TABLE AND ADD SAMPLE DATA
************************************************************************************************/
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    ProductTypeID INT NOT NULL,
    ParentProductID INT NOT NULL,
    Code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ts TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT Products (ID, ProductTypeID, ParentProductID, Code)
VALUES (NEWID(), 1, 1, 'SKU');

/************************************************************************************************
DECLARE INPUT VARIABLES
************************************************************************************************/

DECLARE @SimpleProducttype INT = 2,
        @SimpleProductID INT = 2,
        @Sku VARCHAR(255) = 'SKU',
        @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();


/************************************************************************************************
GENERATE INSERT SCRIPT USING SYS.COLUMNS AND XML CONCATENATION
************************************************************************************************/
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    'INSERT Products (' + 
        STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
                FROM    sys.columns AS c
                WHERE   c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Products')
                AND     c.name != 'ts'
                ORDER BY c.column_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    + ')
    SELECT  ' +
        STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + CASE WHEN c.Name IN ('ProducttypeID', 'ParentProductID', 'ID') THEN '@' + Name
                                ELSE QUOTENAME(c.name)
                            END
                FROM    sys.columns AS c
                WHERE   c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Products')
                AND     c.name != 'ts'
                ORDER BY c.column_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') + '
    FROM    Products
    WHERE   Code = @sku;';
/************************************************************************************************
EXECUTE THE SCRIPT
************************************************************************************************/
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    @SQL, 
    N'@ParentProductID INT, @ProductTypeID INT, @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @Sku VARCHAR(255)', 
    @ParentProductID = @SimpleProductID,
    @ProducttypeID = @SimpleProducttype,
    @ID = @ID,
    @Sku = @Sku;
```

The script this generates for the sample table is:

```
INSERT Products ([ID],[ProductTypeID],[ParentProductID],[Code])
SELECT  @ID,@ProductTypeID,@ParentProductID,[Code]
FROM    Products
WHERE   Code = @sku;
```

It is an **UGLY** hack and I do not suggest you use this, I am posting it to show how much simpler it would be to just list the columns, and every time your schema changes, make a change to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise creating a view which returns all columns except the timestamp.
You will need to ensure the view is kept up to date, but this will allow the update scripts themselves to function without specifying columns explicitly.

Your script would look like this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Products
FROM vwProducts
WHERE Code = @sku

Update #products 
SET Code = Code+'Group',
    ProducttypeID = @SimpleProducttype,
    ParentProductID = @SimpleProductID,
    ID = NEWID()

INSERT vwProducts
SELECT * FROM #Products
```

Answer (score 0):

You musn't use `select *`

One way is removing the `timespan` from the column list:

```
INSERT INTO Products ( [Col1],[Col2],[Coln] )
       VALUES ( 'ValueCol1','ValueCol2','ValueCol' )
```

The second method is to specify DEFAULT as the value in the `timestamp` column:

```
INSERT INTO Products  ( [Col1], [Timestamp] )
       VALUES ( 'Col1Value', DEFAULT )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about the value in the timestamp/rowversion field, you can define it as binary(8) on the copy table. Then you do not need to list out the columns.